# Xamarin form: icons/image not showing which usually work before

Tags: image, xamarin, ffimageloading

Having problem not showing the ffimageloading image on the listview on iOS12.1.3 later by the client and it happened many time even though not always but it works on my local ipad, which i am not sure how to tackle.

Now it looks like also affecting the android devices. The client used to be working and it's now not working

I have initialize the init function in AppDelegate which is required otherwise my device also won't see.

Only thing i have inside was an delayloading and downSampleToViewSize which i am not sure what cause it.

Comment: If the question is nothing more than 'doesn't work sometimes under unknown circumstances' it should be closed... you probably even know that...

My guess would be if those are images from the web that they simply don't download sometimes from some server and some provider, that would perfectly fit the details that you have provided.

Comment: not the web. is the assets of project. What is the best way to find that unknown circumstances if i can't find the unknown.

Comment: I guess this happens in release mode, as you say "the client". Can you plug your iphone/android, launch the device log tool of VS and see if there is any error in the log when image does not show ?